# Which is better way to declare color between in resource file and assign a color to val directly when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I create a new Jetpack Compose project using the Android Studio wizard, I find color in both the resource XML file and Kotlin file.

I need to use colors for both Compose fun and Non compose fun, which is the better way between Code A and Code B?

**Code A**

```
val Purple200 = Color(0xFFBB86FC)
val Purple500 = Color(0xFF6200EE)
```

**Code B**

```
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>   
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project has both Jetpack compose code and view-based code.
Use the colors directly from the XML resource file.

[colorResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#colorResource(kotlin.Int))

```
colorResource(R.color.purple_200)
```

The above code can access the XML color resources from Compose functions.

---

This way is okay if you are migrating a View-based project to Jetpack Compose.

But, if you are starting a new complete Compose project or after complete migration of a view-based project to Jetpack compose, it is recommended to use the colors from the `Colors.kt` file.

---

**Note:**
This answer is not opinion based.
Jetpack compose can access colors from XML resources properly.
But the other way (accessing color using code in a View-based system) is not possible.

We have to consider the component theme, feature theme, dark or light mode, etc as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add your colors to **Color.kt** file

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

val Purple80 = Color(0xFFD0BCFF)
val PurpleGrey80 = Color(0xFFCCC2DC)
val Pink80 = Color(0xFFEFB8C8)
```

Directly access from the compose as follows

```
RadioButton(
            selected = selected,
            onClick = onSelected,
            colors= RadioButtonDefaults.colors(
                selectedColor = Radio_Button_Selected,
                unselectedColor = Radio_Button_UnSelected
            )
        )
```